# Build a regular expression to define a regular language

Tags: regex, regular-language

The language is an infinite set of chains that are defined by the next conditions.

Conditions:

```
1) The language chains may consist of symbols from the set {1,a,b}. 
2) The language chains always start from subchain '1a'.
3) Every languange chain has to include at least one subchain 'aa'.
```

For example:

```
1aa, 1abaa, 1aaab, 1aab1a, ... etc.
```

My decision is:

```
1a (1+a+b)* a (1+a+b)*
```

But I'm not quite sure if it's correct. Is it correct?

Comment: Besides the point, but that doesn't look like a *regular* grammar to me ;-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution will void condition 3. It will ensure only `a` subchain. For example, it will match `1abab` which does not contain `aa`. Here's one which I have found working:

`1a(a[1ab]*|[1ab]*aa[1ab]*)`

This begins with 1a. Then based on whether the next character is a (as in 1aa, which will satisfy all 3 conditions btw), searches for any combination of 1, a and b or any combination with an `aa` in it.

Note: In your notation of formal language, the given regex be like:

`1a((a(1+a+b)*)+((1+a+b)*aa(1+a+b)*))`

Comment: But 1aa does not match this one.

Comment: @FelixFrank Thanks. I'll improve the regex.

Comment: Why? (1+a+b)* can also be a void symbol or 'lambda'. I mean: 1a NULL a NULL or 1aa

Comment: @user3470412 sure. But it can also **not** be either of the two. As I said, your regex will match `1abab` which voids condition 3. You'll need to construct a regex which will not match anything else than something which satisfies all 3 conditions.

Comment: But how to write your solution in the form I offered? Since  operations like '|' are not allowed and I don't have instruments to check the validity of my solutions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try delve into essense of this solution.

Comment: Can I somehow get rid of those parens () which are without the symbol of endless Klini iteration * next to them? I have only one example in my theory and it uses ()* only. Let me write this example here. The language is defined by a set {0,1,a,b}*. Conditions: (1) All chains have to end on '01a'; (2) All chains have to include only an even quantity of 'a' symbols. Example: a01a, ab01a,aaa01a. The correct solution will be this: ((0+1+b)*a(0+1+b)*a(0+1+b)*)*(0+1+b)*a(0+1+b)*01a. It contains only iteration parens ()* but no priority parens ().

Comment: I think this solution for my problem might be correct too: 1a (a (1+b)*)* a ((1+b)* a)*.

Comment: But doesn't include `1abaa`.

Comment: May be this one will be correct?

    1a ((1+b)* a)* (a (1+b)*)* a (1+b+a)*

This solution will allow 1abaa and ignore things like: 1aba, 1abab.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cannot form a single regex that will be matched by all and only those strings that match your criteria.

Comment: `1a(a[1ab]*|[1ab]*aa[1ab]*)` I think this is spotless.

Comment: Ooh, consider my hat tipped :-)

Comment: But how to write your solution in the form I offered? Since operations like '|' are not allowed and I don't have instruments to check the validity of my solutions.